# Iterate over an array of objects

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, ruby-hash

I have got an array of objects in object and trying to reduce to specific form of array. For example:

```
[
  #<Item name: "Item 1", content: #<Item value: #<Item quantity: val1>, #<Item 
quality: val2>>,
  #<Item name: "Item 2", content: #<Item value: #<Item quantity: val1>, #<Item 
quality: val2>>,
  #<Item name: "Item 3", content: #<Item value: #<Item quantity: val1>, #<Item 
quality: val2>>,
  #<Item name: "Item 4", content: #<Item value: #<Item quantity: val1>, #<Item 
quality: val2>>,
  #<Item name: "Item 5", content: #<Item value: #<Item quantity: val1>, #<Item 
quality: val2>>
]
```

should be reduce to

```
[ [Item1, [val1, val2]], [Item2, [val1, val2]], [Item3, [val1, val2]], [Item4, 
[val1, val2]], [Item5, [val1, val2]]]
```

I have tried

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
array.each do |array|
 arr1 << array.name
  arr2 << array.value.quantity
   arr2 << array.value.quality
   arr1 << arr2
 end
```

The output of the above code is

```
[ Item1,  [val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2], 
Item2, [[val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2,val1,val2]....]
```

The problem with this code it does not stop iterate per object what i mean is for Item1 it should be only val1 and val2 only for Item1.

Comment: is the Items object a result of database query? i ask this, if you wanna get an array, this should be done with `pluck`

Comment: no, the items object is not a result of database query.

Answer (score 5):

I would start with something like this:

```
array.map do |element|
  [element.name, [element.value.quantity, element.value.quality]]
end
```